# Symfony 4 with Hateoas: Relations with Child class

Tags: rest, symfony, hateoas

I have a parent class MapItem, and a child class, MapExhibit. My MapExhibit class has a property, $builiding, which ties the exhibit to a particular MapBuilding entity. When the API calls for the JSON, the $building should not appear for MapExhibit entities in particular.

Note I am using the [willdurand/Hateoas](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas#exclusion) bundle

Here is my current setup:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Map\MapItemRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"item" = "MapItem", "bathroom" = "MapBathroom", "building" = "MapBuilding", "bus" = "MapBus", "emergency" = "MapEmergency", "exhibit" = "MapExhibit", "parking" = "MapParking"})
 * @Serializer\XmlRoot("mapItem")
 * @Hateoas\Relation("self", href = "expr('/api/mapitems/' ~ object.getId())")
 */
abstract class MapItem
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Serializer\XmlAttribute
    */
    private $id;

    ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Map\MapExhibitRepository")
 *
 * @Hateoas\Relation(
 *    "building",
 *    exclusion = @Hateoas\Exclusion()
 * )
 */
class MapExhibit extends MapItem
{
   ...

   /**
    * Many emergency devices can belong to one building.
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MapBuilding", inversedBy="emergencyDevices")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="building_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
    */
   private $building;

   ...

   public function getBuilding(): ?MapBuilding
   {
       return $this->building;
   }
}
```

The result is a JSON object that includes the relation from the parent MapItem

```
"_links":{"self":{"href":"\/api\/mapitems\/29"}}}]
```

But also includes the data from the exhibit's building. This part should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [exclusion strategies](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) in documentation.

> If you would like to always expose, or exclude certain properties. Then, you can do this with the annotations @ExclusionPolicy, @Exclude, and @Expose.
>
> The default exclusion policy is to exclude nothing. That is, all properties of the object will be serialized. If you only want to expose a few of the properties, then it is easier to change the exclusion policy, and only mark these few properties: (...)

So basically, put `@Serializer\Exclude()` above `private $builidng`. Don't forget to add `use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;` on top.